# Dropdown list for navbar

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am building a navbar using HTML, CSS and JS. I am having issues with the JS portion that is supposed to make the toggle button drop down and show all of the available links when the page is resized. When I debug my code, I get an error message stating 'cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null'. How could I fix this issue?

HTML

```
    <div class='Navbar'>

 <a href=''>EVENTS</a>

 <a href=''>FOOD</a>

 <a href=''>FUN</a>

 <img id='center-logo' src='img/SAMO.png'>  

        <a href=''>VISIT</a>

        <a href=''>GET INVOLVED</a>

        <a href=''>HISTORY</a> 

        <div style="font-size: 20px;" id='Navbar_Link-Toggle'>

            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>

        </div> 

    </div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

  img,

  .Navbar {

    text-align: left;

    margin-top: 2%;

  }

  a {

margin-left: 0;


    display: none;

  }

  .Navbar__ToggleShow {

    display: flex;

  }

#Navbar_Link-Toggle {

  align-self: flex-end;

  display: initial;

  float: right;

  margin-top: 2%;

}

}
```

JS

```
const toggle = document.querySelector('#Navbar_Link-Toggle');

const nav = document.querySelector('#Navbar_Link-Toggle')

const toggleMenu = () => {

  const tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    tags.forEach(tag => 

tag.classList.toggle('Navbar__ToggleShow'));

}

nav.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

Comment: Most probably document.querySelector('#Navbar_Link-Toggle') returns null. And also why is toggle and nav selected in the same manner. That smells fishy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly iterate nodelist, as `typeyof nodelist` is not `array` but it is `object`, hence to iterate the same, you have to convert nodelist into array first using `Array.prototype.forEach.call`, please replace JS code with below and see :

```
const toggle = document.querySelector('#Navbar_Link-Toggle');

const nav = document.querySelector('#Navbar_Link-Toggle')

const toggleMenu = () => {

const tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(tags, function (tag) {
 console.log(tag);
 tag.classList.toggle('Navbar__ToggleShow');
});

}

nav.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```